# Callback in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, callback

I want to call a function after a particular form is submitted in my mobile app. I am calling it as :

```
after_save :insert_into_my_table, on: :save_playing_request
```

save_playing_request is the function which saves the new form. I want to call insert_into_my_table after this. Is it the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not correct way, I think you should use conditional callback or you can also try to customize this as per your requirement.

Like below code.

save_playing_request is just save the data then it should return true/false.
then we can use 'if' with callback.

```
after_save :insert_into_my_table, if: :save_playing_request?
```

Now you need to change your method name.

```
save_playing_request => save_playing_request?
```

Comment: What should be the condition?

Comment: My save_playing_request method saves the data from the form into a playing requests table. Still, is your method of writing callback correct?